# Monitor and control a ROS robot via a server

Tags: ros, websocket, topic, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

What do you think is the best solution to transparently forward some of the ROS topics of a robot to the special server computer through the Internet? So several operators could (via web interface) view the state of robots and send commands to them (via topics or services).

It can be developed using HTTPS interface, or WebSockets, or raw TCP/UDP; different storages for messages can be used (SQL, MongoDB, Redis). Or maybe some ready solution for such tasks?

Please, make some advises.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269043/monitor-and-control-a-ros-robot-via-a-server/) by [okalachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/31609/okalachev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rosbridge_suite](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) is a ROS WebSocket server that's very useful for creating web interfaces to ROS systems. On the client side, [roslib_js](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs) provides interfaces to handle the data from rosbridge WebSockets.

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-08-18**:
Also see http://robotwebtools.org

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-18**:
[rosnodejs](http://wiki.ros.org/rosnodejs) might be more suitable than `rosbridge_suite`, but that depends on scale of the application and integration requirements.

**Comment by [okalachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/31609/okalachev/) on 2017-08-18**:
Thanks for the answer!

rosbridge is a great thing, but it requires the robot to be the WebSocket server, so the user should be in the same local network with the robot, and connect to the robot directly.

**Comment by [okalachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/31609/okalachev/) on 2017-08-18**:
What I need, is that robot is connected to some server in the Internet, and any other user (with permissions) can go to this server with a regular browser, and monitor and control it.

**Comment by [okalachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/31609/okalachev/) on 2017-08-18**:
gvdhoorn, I don't understand, how rosnodejs can help in this?